# Roles usuario-admin en una aplicacion de angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, express, jwt

estoy haciendo una aplicacion con express como backend y angular como frontend.

El problema es que no sé como gestionar los usuarios al momento de que inicien sesión, para que un usuario comun sea redirigido a un dashboard y un admin a otro.

Como informacion adicional,

- En la base de datos existe una columna para identificar a cada usuario (admin o vacio).
- El backend esta funcionando correctamente con JWT, genera el token y lo esta almacenando en
  localstorage en angular.
- El registro y inicio de sesion funcionan correctamente.

Hasta ahora solo he logrado diferenciar a los usuarios por su estado (res.status) al momento de realizar la peticion(login) en el backend, pero creo que no es la mejor opción.

Espero sus ideas o recomendaciones.
Gracias!!

Comment: Ten en cuenta que las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions). Haz que tu pregunta se limite a un problema _en específico_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

la función debería ser muy parecida a esta. Pero para mayor control te recomiendo usar Guards que nos permiten hacer diferentes validaciones antes de ingresar a una vista/pagina/ruta y hacer redirecciones si es el caso.

```
private login(username: string, password: string): void {
    this.authService.login(username, password)
        .subscribe(response => {
            if (response.status === 'USER') {
                this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
                return;
            }
            this.router.navigate(['/admin-dashboard']);
        });
}
```

Documentación de Guards: https://binary-coffee.dev/post/guards-en-angular-como-funcionan